# How to have cmake unpack my compiler

Tags: cmake

In order to ensure that my Linux builds are identical regardless of the distribution the build host uses, I have packaged up my compiler and the sysroot files into a relocatable tar file and checked that into source control.

So the first step in any build (or at least, a step that must be invoked before any compile step) must be to extract this tar file.

If I was using a makefile, this would be simple to do.  However, the project is using cmake and I can't figure out any way to do it with cmake.  It might even be that I need this extract step invoked before cmake starts to detect the compiler: I can hard-code the compiler name but if cmake fails if it can't find the compiler then I need the unpack to happen before that test.

Is this possible with cmake?

Comment: Why would anyone sane want to install a compiler from an unkown source? This seems to be a major security problem. Specify the compiler version / library versions properly in your CMakelist.txt and throw an error if wrong versions are installed.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The compilers are not from an unknown source: I built them myself from source code.  I do not want to force everyone to use identical distributions and versions of distributions, get every development system to upgrade in lockstep every time we change our product compiler and never upgrade anything until that happens, etc.  Instead I bundle a known compiler + libraries + headers and always use that compiler to build.  This removes any version dependency at all of my build from the system hosting the build.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`execute_process`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aexecute_process) to invoke cmake's cross-platform command mode ([`cmake -E tar`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#opt%3a-E)).  The command would be something like:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xvf MyCompiler.bz2)
```

The command which causes CMake to check for a valid compiler is [`project`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aproject), so as long as you have your `execute_process` call before the `project` call, the unpacking will be done before the compiler check.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  Unfortunately we build for multiple systems including Windows, OSX, and Solaris as well as Linux and not all of those support the bundled compiler (yet...?)  So I need to unpack this only on some systems.  However, it appears that the standard variables like CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM and CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME are not defined until after the project call... catch-22 ? :-(

Comment: I think maybe the variables `WIN32`, `UNIX` and `APPLE` are available before the `project` call, but that's probably not fine-grained enough for you.  So yes - catch 22 on this front.  However, you could always add something like `execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E environment OUTPUT_VARIABLE ThisEnv)` before `project` to capture the current environment to the variable `ThisEnv` and then assess it using [`string(REGEX MATCH ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:string).

Comment: Thanks Fraser.  It looks like I'll have to do something tricky.  I've heard very good things about cmake, and it does seem to generate outputs for its various targets flawlessly which is great.  But I'm surprised (and a bit frustrated) by how inflexible and limited it is in some respects, especially dealing with more advanced environments like cross-compilation, etc.  Thanks for your response here!